# mongo(aggregate) how to filter pairs with 2 crossed ids

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is my use case:

*I perform a join aggregation (using $lookup) from two collections A & B.
The result (after $unwind) contains a large set of documents each containing one pair of related documents from the join. And since the pairs are reflexive, We get pairs like: (_id1, ns: [_id2] ) and (_id2, ns[_id1]).*

=> The question is how to get rid of one of the equivalent pairs

Let's detail the complete process:

```
A = db.A;
A.drop();

nobjects = 100; window = 180.0;

for (i = 0; i < nobjects; i++) { obj = {'loc': [ (_rand()*2*window - window), (_rand()*2*window - window) ] }; A.insert(obj); }

print('A count=', A.count());
A.createIndex({ 'loc': '2d'});

ra = 0.; decl = 0.; ext = 50.0; bottomleft = [ ra - ext, decl - ext ]; topright = [ ra + ext, decl + ext ];

B = db.B;
B.drop();

p1 = [{$geoNear: {near: [0, 0], query: { 'loc': { $geoWithin: {$box: [bottomleft, topright] } } }, distanceField: 'dist', }}, {$out: 'B'},];

A.aggregate(p1, {allowDiskUse: true} );

print('B count=', B.count());

dx =   { $abs: {$subtract: [ {$arrayElemAt: ['$ns.loc', 0]}, {$arrayElemAt: ['$loc', 0]}] } };
dx2 =  { $multiply: [dx, dx] };
dy =   { $abs: {$subtract: [ {$arrayElemAt: ['$ns.loc', 1]}, {$arrayElemAt: ['$loc', 1]}] } };
dy2 =  { $multiply: [dy, dy] };
dist = { $sqrt:  { $add: [ dx2, dy2] } };

p2 = [ {$geoNear: { near: [0, 0], query: { loc: { $geoWithin: {$box: [bottomleft, topright] } } }, limit: nobjects, distanceField: 'dist', } },
       {$lookup: {'from':'B', localField:'A.loc', foreignField:'B.loc', as:'ns'} },
       {$unwind: '$ns'},
       {$redact: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$_id', '$ns._id'] }, '$$PRUNE', '$$KEEP' ] } },
       {$addFields: {dist: dist} },
       {$project: {'_id': 1, 'ns._id':1}},
     ];

cursor = A.aggregate(p2, {allowDiskUse: true});
```

Running this script results in:

```
> load('j.js')
A count= 100
B count= 6
true
> cursor
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db5"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db2") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db5"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc0") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db5"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db6") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db5"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc8") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db5"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9da4") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db2"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db5") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db2"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc0") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db2"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db6") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db2"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc8") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db2"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9da4") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc0"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db5") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc0"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db2") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc0"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db6") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc0"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc8") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc0"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9da4") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db6"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db5") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db6"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db2") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db6"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc0") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db6"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9dc8") } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9db6"), "ns" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5911c0445562f6b9815f9da4") } }
```

looking precisely, the result contains documents like:

```
{_id: 'aaa', ns: {_id:'bbb'} }
...
{_id: 'bbb', ns: {_id:'aaa'} }
...
```

Of course those two documents (id1, ns(id2)) & (id2, ns(id1)) are equivalent (since the pairs don't need to be ordered), thus we only need one of those two.

how can I do this filtering?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion

Christian

Comment: Are you sure your join part is working correctly ? It looks to me you are joining each document in collection 1 with all documents from collection 2.  For example take a look at this record `{_id: 'aaa', loc: [x1, y1], ns: [_id:'bbb', loc: [x2, y2] ] }`  the location is not matching here which is join criteria.

Comment: In order to explain what we want to do: The original collection is made of objects that have a 2D position (the "loc" field). the original purpose is to consider a "region" in the plane, then to find all neighbours which respective distance is lower than a maximum distance.

Comment: (cont'ed)... the complete aggregation works perfectly, besides the fact that the pairs of neighbours is dupplicated because every pair of objects is found twice. I may send here the complete aggregation, with the complete algorithm, together a method to generate random objects. However, I think that I might understand your point, but there is a missing operation not mentioned in my simplified example: the filtering operation that selects pairs with a distance lower that a max distance. Without this filter, I agree that I get ALL pairs inside the selected region.

Comment: Please look at the new version of the question provided with a complete and working example.

Comment: Thank you for creating a complete example and explaining the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A.loc` and `B.loc` are not valid fields and is the reason for cross product.

Your `$lookup` should be `{$lookup: {'from':'B', localField:'loc', foreignField:'loc', as:'ns'} }`.This will result in left join as it should be.

So as per example the aggregate should only result ( after `$lookup` stage ) in 100 documents (leaving the geo part aside) with *some* of them will have a match in `ns` and non match is returned as  `[]` `ns` arrays.

So the second part of query will be

```
{ $lookup: {'from':'B', localField:'loc', foreignField:'loc', as:'ns'} }
{ $unwind: '$ns'}, //will also drop the `[]` ns 
{ $redact: { $cond: [{ $gt: ['$_id', '$ns._id'] }, '$$PRUNE', '$$KEEP' ] } },
{ $addFields: {dist: dist} },
{ $project: {'_id': 1, 'ns._id':1} }
```

The `$gt` will take care of dropping the one of the reflexive pair.

Comment: Thanks for this analysis. I keep the point on $gt which actually solved my question. Atherwise, I maintain my syntax on the $lookup since I really need the cross product, to get all pairs of neighbour objects. Thanks anyway for the hint!!

Comment: Actually I kept the query as I formulated originally, simply replacing the "$eq" expression with "$gte", in the $redact operation. You can play with the example and you will see the result exactly as I expected it.

Comment: Remember that I wanted "all pairs of objects which distance is lower that a maximum value (inside a given sub-region of the plane)".